# Oracle equivalent of PostgreSQL ARRAY_AGG

Tags: postgresql, oracle, aggregate

I'm looking for an aggregate function supported by Oracle SQL to collect values into arrays, something similar to PostgreSQL `ARRAY_AGG`. I already use `listagg` for strings, I use `cast()` with `collect()` and `multiset()` but it requires to declare a table type. Is there a more straightforward way of emulating `ARRAY_AGG` with Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to emulate `ARRAY_AGG` with Oracle SQL without declaring new types only in very simple cases when build-in types can do the job, for example `sys.odcivarchar2list` (varray of varchar2) and `sys.odcinumberlist` (varray of number), with `cast()` and `collect()` or `multiset()`:

```
select 
   cast(multiset(select id from my_pretty_table order by id) as sys.odcinumberlist)
from 
   dual;

select
   cast(collect(id order by id) as sys.odcinumberlist)
from
   my_pretty_table;
```

Note that this solution is still a lot less flexible than PostgreSQL `ARRAY_AGG`.